# Image not loading in Express JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

In Express I wrote these lines of code:

```
res.write("The current temperature is "+temp+". ");
res.write("Weather is currently "+weatherDes);
res.write("<img src=" +imageURL+ ">");
res.send();
```

But the image is not loading. Can anyone help?

Comment: You have to make another route that will return the `image`, you never returning the image from the server, you just provided the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using "res.send"

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const temp = 10;
    const weatherDes = 20;
    const imageURL = "https://dog.png";

    let html = "The current temperature is: " + temp + ".\n";
    html += "Weather is currently: " + weatherDes + ".\n"
    html += '<img src="' + imageURL +'" width="50" height="50">';

    res.send(html);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Or a better way is using a "view engine" like ejs

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// use res.render to load up an ejs view file

// index page 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    const data = {
        temp: 10,
        weatherDes: 20,
        imageURL: 'https://dog.png'
    };
    res.render('pages/index', data);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

If you decide to use ejs like the last example, you need to create a file "/views/pages/index.ejs" with the content:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Your Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The current temperature is: <%= temp %> </p>
    <p>Weather is currently: <%= weatherDes %> </p>
    <img src="<%= imageURL %>" width="50" height="50">
</body>
</html>
```

Dont forget install ejs

```
npm i ejs
```

And change "https://dog.png" with your image

Comment: I believe ```res.send()``` is deprecated in the latest version of Express. It's probably safer to use ```res.sendStatus()```

Comment: https://expressjs.com/es/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus
res.sendStatus(200) // equivalent to res.status(200).send('OK')